# Keras model predicts differently when predicting based on video frame vs. individual snapshot

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, tensorflow

I'm training a binary image classification model in Keras, with the end goal of parsing through entire videos. I have a script that reads in a few snapshots from training videos and lets the model predict on them. I have another script that reads in a video and runs the model through each individual frame and saves the output to a DataFrame. For some reason, even though many of the images that the image prediction script goes through are pulled straight from a video, the video prediction script will predict completely differently, even though the input image is the same. The video prediction script always predicts the same class for every frame, even for frames that were in the training set.

Here are the prediction parts of my scripts:

```
#Image Prediction
        image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(impath), (300, 300))
        if("y" in gray.lower()):
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        else:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        prediction = model.predict(image)[0]

        print(prediction)
```

```
#Video Prediction
while success:
        success, frame = self.video.read()
        if(not success):
            break
        image = cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        image = image.astype("float") / 255.0

        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        prediction = self.model.predict(image)[0]

        if(prediction < .5):
            prediction = 0
        else:
            prediction = 1
        print(prediction)
```

These two scripts preprocess the images identically, there shouldn't be any reason why the predictions would turn out differently. Using np.array_equal I've deduced that the arrays are not different in size, shape, nor content. I've also used imshow to compare and I can confirm that the two are visually identical.

When I print the prediction values during the video prediction, they're all very close to .5, which shouldn't happen very often, because my loss value should be around .4, which means I should be getting way more .9s and .1s than .5s.

I'm open to any and all ideas. Thank you for your help.